# How can I return an array of Booleans as a result of Array.prototype.every() method?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to map an array in order to get a Boolean for each iteration after comparing two arrays.

1. Compare if the values of array `a` are included into `b`.
2. Get an array of Booleans, returning the result of each iteration made in the `every()` method

I thought of using a combination of `every()` and `map()`

This is how far I went:

```
let a = [1,2,4];
let b = [1,2,3]

let answer = a.every(num => b.includes(num))


console.log(answer)
// returns false
```

I tried placing the `callback` of `every()` inside a `map()` method without success.

I know that `every()` iterates, so somehow it should be easy to the an array of each iteration like:

`[true,true,false]`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just replace `every` with `map` ?

Comment: `every` doesn't return an array. It returns a single Boolean.

Comment: @jonas I am embarrassed of how simple the answer was. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
    let a = [1,2,4];
    let b = [1,2,3]
    
    let answer = a.map(num => b.includes(num))
    
    
    console.log(answer)
```

Use map function

[Map Function docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)